# "Question Favorited by" count set to zero rather than hidden when un-favoriting

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks

When clicking on the *Favorite question* button the count is incremented correctly:

> [image]

But when reverting back, if the count goes from 1 to none, the 1 is decremented to 0.

> [image]

When you refresh the page, it vanishes since questions without favorites do not show the count at all. So showing the zero when unfavoriting isn't necessary.

It appears to be a small bug, in my opinion. What do you think?

Comment: Not my downvote but I can see why someone would downvote you for calling this a bug. I don't have a problem with fixing it for consistency, but that is not a bug IMO - the information that 0 people have favourited the question is correct; it's just not consistent how it's displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minor, and quick to fix.

With you in the next build (rev 2014.7.29.1731, meta rev 2014.7.29.2401).

Comment: And here I was defending not having to change anything. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I wouldn't, but it was a simple one. `count-- <= 0` to `--count <= 0`...

Comment: Ah, yes, assignment in an expression is such a joy to use, especially when you can mix in the order of referencing and assigning the new value so readily. Ahem! :-P

Comment: @Oded .. <= 0? Why that? I mean, I do that too in similar cases just in case, but in that specific case: is it even possible for the value to be negative?

Comment: @1337 - it is a reasonable guard (say a double/triple click - might cause `count` to be under 0)

Comment: @Oded How can that happen? Isn't it that the star instantly disappears when the count is zero again and therefore the double-click can't trigger twice? (Just curious ;))

Comment: @1337 - frankly, I didn't write that code... the check doesn't hurt, so I left it there.